# Double-Tap zooms in Map

Tags: android, skmaps

I am developing an android app with Skobbler.
After updating to the latest version of the Skobbler SDK we got this "bug":
In the past I implemented the `onDoubleTap(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint)` function. This worked and still works.

But now, in addition to the implementation, the SDK zooms in the map, like normal for maps. Double-Tap to zoom.

But in this situation this is not what I want. 
Is there a way to disable the standard functionality of the Double-Tap? 
Again: With the last Version of Skobbler SDK this did not happen.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As Skobbler isn't open source and isn't a free product, I suggest you ask Skobbler why you have this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no - the behaviour was changed to match the iOS implementation and for the time being will remain as is (your input will be considered for future updates)